# How to create 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a 3D array with numpy with dimensions [282][282][256]. I have tried

```
np.zeros((282,282,256))
```

but this is not giving me the correct width and height. How do I create such an array that has 282 width and height, and each cell is an array of 256 elements?

Comment: Your instruction seems correct. Print the shape of your array and tell us what shape you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are doing it right

```
var = np.zeros((282,282,256),dtype=float)
```

but you will access the elements of array as below:

```
var[1,1,2] = 10
var[0,0,3] = 5
```

Comment: if I type var[1,1,2], I am accessing 1st row 1st column, and the 2nd element in that cell's array ?

Comment: array indexing starts at 0, so you are accessing 2nd row, 2nd col and 3rd element